# Prevent autofill input by default value bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a problem with bootstrap datepicker - it autofills an input by default value (current date) at page load, though the input is not selected and / or in focus.
I was trying to investigate reason of such behavior, but all I have found is that datepicker is calling itself on init

```
// copypaste from `bootstrap-datepicker.js`
/* DATEPICKER DATA-API
* ======================= */

$(document).on(
    'focus.datepicker.data-api click.datepicker.data-api',
    '[data-provide="datepicker"]',
    function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('datepicker'))
            return;
        e.preventDefault();
        // component click requires us to explicitly show it
        $this.datepicker('show');
    }
);
$(function(){
    $('[data-provide="datepicker-inline"]').datepicker();
});
```

Maybe someone met such problem before or has any idea how to fix this. The goal is to leave input empty till user changes value manually.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can find your solution here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: unfortunately did not find there any solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in a some chrome extension. Didn't figure out yet which extension is culprit, but in other browsers and in incognito mode chrome the problem does not appear.

Upd: **Oh, I have mistaken. Extensions have nothing to do with it. Damned autofill causes it**

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on the page mentioned above. Kindly have a look at it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what?

Here is my DP-init code:
`$('#dp').datepicker({
        language: 'ru',
        endDate: '0d',
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    });`
Your example differs from mine only by absence of properties in the method.
I tried your example to be sure I am not fully fool, aaand... datepicker still shows up on its own in my case, though I even do not touch mouse or keyboard to trigger calendar!
Of course I've checked whole my code to be sure that nothing else triggers datepicker and I found nothing which could call it.

And I have no idea how to debug it...

Comment: Maybe my explanation is not enough clear. When I load my page, I see already opened datepicker. Seems like somewhere happens `$('#selector').datepicker('show');`
though there is nothing like that in my code.
I tried to debug it with js console in Chrome and it seems that DP triggers after JQuery init

Comment: @IgorVoytovich I was trying to tell you that the date picker itself provides the method which you are searching for and therefore I posted the answer.
If the issue still persist then will have to debug the datetimepicker.js for finding the exact answer